# Conflict in library Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-support-library

I get error when try export to apk file, i use Eclipse

this error messages

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. Fix the build path then try building this project   AppActivity     Unknown Java Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The type android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files   ShareActivity.java  /AppActivity/src/com/brodev/socialapp/view  line 1  Java Problem

And here screenshoot my app

[My Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQDRI.png)

[Second Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYL05.png)

Please help me to fix it.
Thx for all attention

Comment: It will not fix the problem, but I highly recommend you to use `Android Studio` instead, first of all because it has really less compilation problems, and almost all of the Android Community has move to Android Studio too, and you will more likely resolve this kind of problems - which you will not have, has `Android Studio` is awesome ;).

Comment: but Android Studio ea more memory resource

Comment: Maybe it uses more resources, but it works. https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/eclipse-is-dead-for-android-development-and-i-helped-kill-it